# Is the average Shannon entropy of a process equal to that of its time-reversed process?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Consider an infinite sequence of characters $\ldots, x_{t-1}, x_t, x_{t+1}, \ldots$ which each belong to a finite alphabet and are generated according to an arbitrary stochastic process. For example, the alphabet may be the English alphabet and the sequence may be English text. Let $H$ be the average Shannon entropy of the process -- that is, the entropy of the distribution of $x_t$ conditioned on $(x_1, \ldots, x_{t-1})$ averaged across sufficiently large $t$.

Consider now the backwards process $\ldots, x_{t+1}, x_t, x_{t-1}, \ldots$
Let $H'$ be the Shannon entropy of the backwards process (i.e. the entropy conditioned on the "future" instead of the past). In the above example, this corresponds to the observed entropy when reading English text backwards.

For some processes (e.g. when all characters are sampled independently), $H = H'$. Is it the case that $H = H'$ for *all* processes? If not, is there a simple counterexample to this rule?

Comment: Shannon entropy is a property of a probability distribution. If you don't tell us what the distribution of $x_t$ conditional on $(x_1,\dots,x_{t-1})$ resp. that of $x_t$ conditional on $(\dots, x_{t+2},x_{t+1})$ is there is no answer to this question.

Comment: Certainly one cannot calculate $H$ without an explicit distribution, but it's possible that certain identities (such as the one I ask about) could be true independent of the distribution.

Comment: Here's an argument I believe shows this identity is true in a finite version of the question. Consider a finite sequence $x_1, \ldots, x_T$ with arbitrary distribution. The joint entropy of the entire sequence is equal to the sum of the "forwards" conditional entropies *and* equal to the sum of the backwards conditional entropies. The average forwards entropy is thus equal to the average backwards entropy, independent of the disitribution of the RVs